# cloud not resolve CNAME in GCP Cloud DNS

Tags: dns, google-cloud-dns, aiven

We have peered two VPCs. GCP & third party VPC (Aiven).

We have few services in aiven which require to talk with resources in gcp vpc such as elasticsearch, redis etc.

Let's say,

**DNS-CNAME:** *test-elasticsearch.example.io*
**ES-URL:** *test-elasticsearch.aivencloud.com*

We have a cloud DNS zone in GCP VPC. I have configured CNAME for third party service URL which can be only accessed via GCP VPC.

I'm successfully able to ping elasticsearch url from GCP VPC however, I can't ping CNAME.

FYI: the dns-zone is working good. I tested it by creating A record for the same with private ip.

In this, let me know what I can do to troubleshoot it this issue.

UPDATE:
edit 1. no CNAME is working in my cloud DNS.

edit 2. resources in public subnets can resolve but not private subnet resources

kindly help

Comment: Did you put a dot at the end of the CNAME record?

Comment: yes. trailing dot is mandatory

Comment: Can you post anonymised result of ```dig -t ANY```?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is GCP does not resolve CNAME on private zones 
I just tried to reference an AWS load balancer as a CNAME record in private zone and it just does not resolve it's ip. 
GCP calls it CNAME Chasing
[image]